# How do I launch Kubuntu Desktop from SSH?

Tags: server, kubuntu, vps

I have an OVH's VPS server with Kubuntu installed + SSH access.

I would like to access Kubuntu desktob in the browser.

How can it be done ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why any `Desktop Environment` has been installed on the server, I think that `mc` is more then necessary, but if that was done, do this: connect to the server via `SSH` and when you are in terminal just type:

```
startx
```

---

If you want to connect to server via browser, you may want to install [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) onto your server (I guess it's not a problem if `DE` have been already installed), and then use [TeamViewer Management Console](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/).

**note:** TeamViewer is Windows-based program and it goes with `wine` inside.

:-)